# Emacs `Invalid font name`

Tags: emacs, fonts

I am using GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (x86_64-suse-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.6.4). I have custom font Inconsolata-g in my `~/.fonts` folder, and I have set it as Monospace font in `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf`. It works well except Emacs is giving me `error: Invalid font name, -unknown-Inconsolata-g-normal-normal-normal-*-15-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1` at launch.

If I change monospace font, then Emacs launch without problem, but when I do `M-x set-default-font`, and select `-unknown-Inconsolata-g-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1`, I also get `Invalid font name: "-unknown-Inconsolata-g-normal-normal-normal-*-*-*-*-*-m-0-iso10646-1"`.

How could i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Peter Dyballa (http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2013-06/msg00347.html), I fixed this with the following in my `~/.emacs`:

```
 (setq initial-frame-alist '(
   (font . "Monospace-10")
 ))
 (setq default-frame-alist '(
   (font . "Monospace-10")
 ))
```

(I have set `Monospace` to `Inconsolata-g` in my system settings)

Comment: This fix doesn't work for all things in Emacs (for example, flycheck and ansi-term). The only thing that worked completely for me was changing the font name to something without hypens. I described my solution [here](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/29397/13650).